# Great articles/videos/... on non-ACID (distributed) systems? ("Eventually Consistent" etc.)

Tags: architecture, cluster-analysis, distributed-system, acid, eventual-consistency

I'll start with these - IMO brilliant - articles:

- [Base: An Acid Alternative](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1394128) - by Dan Pritchett (eBay), 2008
- [Eventually Consistent (- Revisited)](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html) - by Werner Vogels (Amazon), 2008
- [Brewer's conjecture and the feasibility of consistent, available, partition-tolerant web services](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=564601) (non-free) - by Seth Gilbert, Nancy Lnych (MIT), 2002

I'm interested in more articles on distributed systems, where ACID can't deliver the necessary scalability/availability anymore (or even, where ACID can still deliver in extreme cases).

The articles should focus on the **practical** side (even though I like maths).

One thing I'd find especially interesting: Which rules of thumb / design patterns / ... can be derived from non-ACID architectures?

Comment: what are the non acid transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Is the NoSQL Meeting Announcing the End of the RDBMS Era?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/NoSQL-and-the-End-of-RDBMS-Era)
- [Randy Shoup Discusses the eBay Architecture](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/shoup-ebay-architecture)
- [Scalability Best Practices: Lessons from eBay](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ebay-scalability-best-practices)
- [Drop ACID and think about data](http://blip.tv/file/1949416)
- [Digg and Reddit Have Joined the NoSQL Camp](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/03/Digg-Reddit-NoSQL-Cassandra)
- [NoSQL in the Enterprise](http://www.infoq.com/articles/nosql-in-the-enterprise)
- [NoSQL: If Only It Was That Easy](http://bjclark.me/2009/08/nosql-if-only-it-was-that-easy/)
- [Embracing Concurrency At Scale](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Embracing-Concurrency-At-Scale)
- [Availability & Consistency](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/availability-consistency)
- [Breaking the Relational Chains](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2005/03/07/breaking-the-relational-chains/)

Comment: A very nice link list - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent speech (not an article) by Gregor Hohpe "[Programming the Cloud](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/programming-cloud-gregor-hohpe)". 
There is an answer for your last question.

Comment: Videos are very welcome. I think I'll watch it tonight - thanks!

Comment: Just watched it, a lot of good information and concepts in there (and it's presented very well).

Answer (score 2):

There is a few presentations on [InfoQ](http://infoq.com) on this topic:

- [Embracing Concurrency at Scale](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Embracing-Concurrency-At-Scale) by *Justin Sheehy*
- [Availability & Consistency](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/availability-consistency) by *Werner Vogels*

And don't forget the paper about Amazon Dynamo:

[Dynamo: Amazon’s Highly Available Key-value Store](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html)

Comment: They look very promising! Will watch/read them in the next days.